# Meaning of "A voltage source “likes” an open-circuit load"

Tags: current-source, short-circuit, voltage-source

I read a book *"The Art of Electronics" by Paul Horowitz, Winfield Hill.*
In the book, I saw some phases.

> A voltage source “likes” an open-circuit load and “hates” a short-circuit load
>
> A current source “likes” a short-circuit load and “hates” an open-circuit load

It said *"obviously"* at the end of the first sentence, but I think I need more understanding of what it's meaning by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A voltage source shorted causes current to rise until something overheats or burns out. Therefore shorts are bad for a voltage source and could damage it.

An open circuit for a current source causes the voltage to rise until current flows. Usually the source will reach it's limit and stop regulating current.

Both of those conditions cause the respective sources to stop functioning correctly. Hence they "hate" it. The opposite condition represents no load, hence they "like" not having to work.

Comment: Thank you @user1850479. As far as I understand, In open circuit, current source raises voltage until it reaches its fixed current value but how much voltage it raises it can't reach because it's open circuit so voltage isn't rising up. Nevertheless, current source keeps raising voltage then it makes problem. Am I understanding right?

Comment: @JeongHwi Ra Correct. For an ideal current source you get infinite voltage. For a real one they usually stop regulating and become voltage sources until you put a load.